# React and Material-UI: Uncaught Invariant Violation: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I develop React components using Material-UI:

**This works fine**

*MainView.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';

class MainView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <List>
          <ListItem primaryText="item 1" />
          <ListItem primaryText="item 2" />
          <ListItem primaryText="item 3" />
        </List>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default MainView;
```

**but when I move `<List>` to another component**

*MainView.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyListView from './MyListView';
// this import was removed as unused as <List> moved to MyListView:
// import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';

class MainView extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <MyListView />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

*MyListView.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';

class MyListView extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem primaryText="item 1" />
        <ListItem primaryText="item 2" />
        <ListItem primaryText="item 3" />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default MyListView;
```

**in this case I receive this:**

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...): Only a
>   ReactOwner can have refs. You might be removing a ref to a component
>   that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you
>   have multiple copies of React loaded (details: link).

*main.js*

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/test" component={MainView} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any suggestion to escape this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you show all `import` statement in `MainView.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I see this error if I have added a component to a render method that is either misspelt or not imported - and therefore not defined in the current scope.

If watching the browser console I will see:

```
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!
app.js:90432 [HMR] ReferenceError: NewComponent is not defined
```

However if I refresh the page I then see in both the browser and the server log:

```
Invariant Violation: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be removing a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https:// fb.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).
   at invariant (E:\testing\node-seed\tmp\webpack:\~\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:38:1)
```

Fixing the component name, or importing it, resolves this error in this case.